# Is Timmy Turner's middle name a reference to Star Trek?

Tags: the-fairly-oddparents

Timmy Turner from *The Fairly Oddparents* and James Kirk from *Star Trek* happen to share the middle name "Tiberius". **Is there any indication that this was intentional on the part of *The Fairly Oddparent* writers/creator, as a reference to the earlier TV show?** "Tiberius" doesn't sound to me as a name likely to be given to a boy in the '90s/2000s, so I've always thought it wasn't just a coincidence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2007 behind the scenes special *77 Secrets of The Fairly Odd Parents Revealed!* explicitly states that Tiberius is a reference to Kirk. There are a number of *Star Trek* references in the show too.

His tree house turned into an Enterprise bridge look-alike in the same video which is from the episode "Boy Toy".